# Proving second isomorphism theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'd like to prove that with $I, J$ being ideals in $R$, then $\frac{I}{I \cap J}$ is isomorphic to $\frac{I+J}{J}$. I am stuck at a couple of places.

The idea is to show that $f: I \rightarrow \frac{I+J}{J}$ given by $f(a) = a+J$ is a surjective homomorphism with kernel $I \cap J$, and then apply the first isomorphism theorem.

First of all, with $f$ defined in such a way, if I have an element $a+J \in \frac{I+J}{J}$, this must have a "representative" in $I$, in order for $f$ to be surjective. I am not sure how to show that. I know that $J$ is ideal in $I+J$. And the elements of $\frac{I+J}{J}$ are all elements of the form $a+J$, i.e. all elements in $I+J$ that are congruent to $a$ modulo $J$ (right?), but how can I know that $a \in I$?

The second issue I have is to show that the kernel of $f$ is $I \cap J$. So if $a$ is in the kernel of $f$, I want to show that $a \in J$. Not sure how to do this. If $a \in ker(f)$, then $f(a) = J$, so then $a$ is in both $I$ and $J$. Is that correct?

Comment: For the first issue, you don't need that $a \in I$.  You just need that $(a+J) \cap I \neq \emptyset$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First Issue:** You are mapping into $(I+J)/J$. That means that your elements are of the form $x+J$, with $x\in I+J = \{a+b\mid a\in I,b\in J\}$.

Since you start with $a\in I\subseteq I+J$, the element $a$ is in fact in $I+J$: it can be written as $a+0$, with $a\in I$, $0\in J$. Thus, $a+J$ makes sense as an element of $(I+J)/J$. That tells you the map is at least well-defined set-theoretically.

I'm guessing what you really have is an issue with surjectivity. Well, suppose that $x+J\in (I+J)/J$. That means $x=a+b$, with $a\in I$ and $b\in J$. There is one obvious thing to try, given that you take things in $I$; could it be that $f(a)=x+J$? Remember that equality means "equality of cosets", not "equality of how you write the element".

**Second Issue:** If $a\in\mathrm{ker}(f)$, then $a+J = 0+J$; when are two cosets of $J$ equal? What does that mean for $a$? Conversely, if $a\in I\cap J$, then you need to verify that $a+J = 0+J$ in $(I+J)/J$.